# "Vectorizing" this for-loop in R? (suppressing interaction main effects in lm)

Tags: r, loops, optimization, statistics

When interactions are specified in lm, R includes main effects by default, with no option to suppress them.  This is usually appropriate and convenient, but there are certain instances (within estimators, ratio LHS variables, among others) where this isn't appropriate.

I've got this code that fits a log-transformed variable to a response variable, independently within subsets of the data.

Here is a silly yet reproducible example:

```
id = as.factor(c(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10))
x = rexp(length(id))
y = rnorm(length(id))
logx = log(x)
data = data.frame(id,y,logx)

for (i in data$id){
    sub = subset(data, id==i)   #This splits the data by id
    m = lm(y~logx-1,data=sub)   #This gives me the linear (log) fit for one of my id's
    sub$x.tilde = log(1+3)*m$coef   #This linearizes it and gives me the expected value for x=3
    data$x.tilde[data$id==i] = sub$x.tilde #This puts it back into the main dataset
    data$tildecoeff[data$id==i] = m$coef #This saves the coefficient (I use it elsewhere for plotting)
    }
```

I want to fit a model like the following:

> Y = B(X*id) +e

with no intercept and no main effect of `id`.  As you can see from the loop, I'm interested in the expectation of Y when X=3, constrained the fit through the origin (because Y is a (logged) ratio of Y[X=something]/Y[X=0].

But if I specify

```
m = lm(Y~X*as.factor(id)-1)
```

there is no means of suppressing the main effects of `id`.  I need to run this loop several hundred times in an iterative algorithm, and as a loop it is far too slow.

The other upside of de-looping this code is that it'll be much more convenient to get prediction intervals.

(Please, I don't need pious comments about how leaving out main effects and intercepts is improper -- it usually is, but I can promise that it isn't in this instance).

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: Downvote?  With no comment?  I'd appreciate if whoever downvoted would show the decency to provide justification for why I am somehow off-base.

Comment: While I'm not the downvoter, I can guess.  Your code is not reproducible, and additionally the steps in the loop are not well-explained.  It is hard to follow what you're doing there, so it is impossible to determine if it can be vectorized, or if it is appropriate to do so.  Please clean this up, or it will likely be voted to be closed as too localized.

Comment: To solve issue #1, I think you'd be better off using something like `split` on your dataframe to split by `data$expid` and then `lapply` or `sapply` your calculations over each subset. That would remove the `for` loop. I can't comment on whether the model is statistcally appropriate to use in this method, but that will get you there from a coding perspective.

Comment: Thanks for that comment, but I think it'd be even faster if I could just fit the model with interactions and no main effects.  If I could do that, I could use `predict(m, newdata=data.frame(id=data$id,x = rep(log(1+3),length=nrow(data)))` thereby losing the two last lines of the loop

Comment: I don't think the premise of this question is true. `lm(y~x1:x2)` fits a model with only an interaction term but no main effect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
m <- lm(y ~ 0 + logx : as.factor(id))
```

see [R-intro '11.1 Defining statistical models; formulae'](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Formulae-for-statistical-models)

Comment: Sometimes the obvious things are the hardest to google.  Thanks!